# developerstudio12.6 CC on Solaris intel i386, compiler do not show errors or warnings but fails

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, solaris, compiler-warnings, sunstudio

Trying to compile C++ program using developerstudio12.6 CC on Solaris intel  i386.
compiler do not show errors or warnings but fails.

Possible to figure why CC do not show any warnings or errors - what is possibly going wrong?

```
developerstudio12.6/bin/CC  -mt -xtarget=native -m32 -g  -errwarn=%all  -O -DNDEBUG  -c xml_test.cc -I<some include> -I<some other include> -o xml_test.o
echo $?
2
```

Using  -verbose=template => similar output, no debug lines
Using -# or verbose=diags=> Huge amount of output but no error lines

```
### CC: Note: NLSPATH =   `/opt/developerstudio12.6/bin/../lib/locale/%L/LC_MESSAGES/%N.cat:/opt/developerstudio12.6/bin/../../lib/locale/%L/LC_MESSAGES/%N.cat`
###     command line files and options (expanded):
### -mt=yes -xtarget=native -xchip=broadwell -xcache=32/64/8/2:256/64/8/2:30720/64/20/24 -xarch=avx2_i -m32 -xdebuginfo=line,param,variable,tagtype,codetag,decl -xglobalize=yes -xpatchpadding=fix -Qoption driver -dconditional=yes -xkeep_unref=funcs,vars -verbose=diags -O3 -DNDEBUG -c xml_test.cc -I<some include> -I<some include> -oxml_test.o
/opt/developerstudio12.6/lib/compilers/bin/ccfe -D__SunOS_5_11 -D__SunOS_RELEASE=0x051100 -D__SUNPRO_CC=0x5150 -D__unix -D__SVR4__ -D__svr4__ -D__SVR4 -D__sun -D__sun__ -D__SunOS -D__i386 -D__i386__ -D__ORDER_LITTLE_ENDIAN__=1234 -D__ORDER_BIG_ENDIAN__=4321 -D__BYTE_ORDER__=__ORDER_LITTLE_ENDIAN__ -D__BUILTIN_VA_ARG_INCR -Dunix -Dsun -Di386 -D__FP_FAST_FMA__ -D__FP_FAST_FMAF__ -D_REENTRANT -D__SUN_PREFETCH -D__SUNPRO_CC_COMPAT=5 -I<some include> -I<some include> -I-xbuiltin -I/opt/developerstudio12.6/lib/compilers/include/CC/Cstd -I/opt/developerstudio12.6/lib/compilers/include/CC -I/opt/developerstudio12.6/lib/compilers/include/cc -DNDEBUG -ptf /tmp/ccfe.1620226479.15666.03.%1.%2 -ptx /opt/developerstudio12.6/bin/CC -ptk "-mt=yes -xtarget=native -m32 -xdebuginfo=line,param,decl,variable,tagtype,codetag -xglobalize=yes -xpatchpadding=fix -xkeep_unref=funcs,vars -verbose=diags -O3 -DNDEBUG -c -I<some include> -I<some include> " -compat=5 -xglobalize=yes -xdebuginfo=line,param,variable,tagtype,codetag,decl -instlib=/opt/developerstudio12.6/lib/compilers/libCstd.a -xdbggen=dwarf+usedonly+incl+line+param+variable+tagtype+codetag+decl -xF=%none -xbuiltin=%default -xldscope=global -xivdep=loop -xdepend -O3 -xarrayloc xml_test.cc -ptb xml_test.o -o /tmp/ccfe.1620226479.15666.01.ir 2> /tmp/ccfe.1620226479.15666.02.err
```

/opt/developerstudio12.6/lib/compilers/stdlibfilt -stderr < /tmp/ccfe.1620226479.15666.02.err

Answer (score 0):

Your `NLSPATH` environment variable is incorrect.

`/opt/developerstudio12.6/bin/../../lib/locale/%L/LC_MESSAGES/%N.cat` refers to `/opt/lib/locale/%L/LC_MESSAGES/%N.cat` instead of `/opt/developerstudio12.6/lib/locale/%L/LC_MESSAGES/%N.cat` because you have an extra `..` element in it.

Comment: Well Andrew the NLS path is not being set by me explicitely, compiler is picking it by itself. I fixed the issue just a while back by adding  -filt=%none to the compiler options:

-mt -xtarget=native -m32  -filt=%none -g2 -verbose=template -errtags -library=iostream

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the issue just a while back by adding `-filt=%none` to the compiler options:

```
-mt -xtarget=native -m32 -filt=%none -g2 -verbose=template -errtags -library=iostream
```